# Is there a SurfacePopup control in Surface 2?

Tags: wpf, popup, touch, pixelsense

We've been working on an application for the last few months that's aimed at Windows 7 tablet PCs. So we've used the Surface 2 SDK for most controls and it's all touch-happy.

I have noticed recently, though, that one of our custom controls isn't working as it should. This control provides popout menus, and these are achieved through the Popup control. On a developer's laptop, this works fine and the menus vanish when you click away from them. I've noticed, though, that on our test tablet they have a tendency to stay open.

I found that there was a SurfacePopup in the first Surface SDK, but I can't find one in the Surface 2 SDK. Did they get rid of it? Is there a 'best practice' approach?

If there's no simple solution, I may have to go old-school and add a window-sized hidden SurfaceButton below the menu when it appears, that hides itself and the menu when clicked or touched.

Beyond that I've noticed that sometimes the SurfaceScrollViewer within the popups won't work. I'm guessing this is because it's not picking up touch events properly. I tried adding this extension method to the window..

```
this.EnableSurfaceInput();
```

..but I get a NullReferenceException on `System.Windows.Input.Mouse.get_LeftButton()` which bizarrely suggests that it can only enable surface inputs for controls when there's a mouse plugged in.

Any ideas? They'll all be welcomed with open arms!

Comment: We're currently facing the same problem...did you find out anything?

Comment: Actually, yes - I'll add an answer so that everyone can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of Daniel, and anyone else who needs a solution to this, I'll try to cast my mind back two years and explain how we got this working.

As far as I can remember, the answer was to use an adorner layer instead of a popup. Basically, every WPF control has an adorner layer, which sits above the control's UI stack. By default it contains nothing, but you can add whatever you like to it.

I got this all working by writing a custom control that allows you to place that control, with content, in the XAML and then show and hide it whenever you need to. When it's shown, it moves its contents into the adorner layer of the containing window, and when it's hidden it moves the contents back into the control itself, which is hidden from the user.

Afraid I can't go into any more detail than that, but as far as I can remember this was the ultimate solution; replacing popups (which never quite worked very well) with a custom control that uses the adorner layer.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think your solution wouldn't have worked for us as we were trying to get Telerik's GridView to work which requires a popup for the filter, but fortunately I found another solution (see other answer).
But still, thanks for sharing! Anyone else suffering from this problem now has two possibilities. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no SurfacePopup in the Surface SDK 2.0, however you can use a normal WPF popup. Then you need to make sure that it receives Touch Events by using the extension method you suggested above **on the popup, not the window**:

`((HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(popup)).EnableSurfaceInput();`

Edit: As I just found out, this only works when the popup is initially open. To get it to work when the popup is opened later on, you don't need to use the popup, but the parent of it's child (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038341/floating-custom-touch-control-in-wpf)).